# 2 Chromium windows

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to open up 2 separate Chromium windows using /.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart. I am able to open both urls when adding two lines but they open in the same browser as two tabs. I would like to open them in two separate windows. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked [through this](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to see if you can get what you want that way?

Comment: Thanks, that is a great resource. I have been able to create two windows with the --new-window switch on two lines . The issue is that the window size and position is only following the first --window-size and --window-position switch. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're better off researching chromium usage on a larger exchange, e.g., [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or possibly [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  Or somewhere like reddit where there are groups dedicated specifically to chromium, or even from the chromium devs themselves, who surely have at least one mail list and IRC channel.  First you find out if it is possible period, then if it doesn't work on the Pi, drill down on that.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this here so hopefully it will help others.

After a bit of digging I found out the tricks to get this working.

First in Chromium you need to create a new user, (doesn't matter what it's called).

Then when editing /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Use the following

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --new-window --start-fullscreen http://google.com --window-position=0,0 --user-data-dir=Default --start-fullscreen
@chromium-browser --new-window --start-fullscreen http://bbc.co.uk --window-position=0,0 --user-data-dir='Profile 1' --start-fullscreen
```

Note the --user-data-dir setting and the --window-position setting, basically you need to treat the two screens as one big screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding some information to the first comment posted here...

Firstly I made another Profile in chromium of course, thats pretty easy.

What I then did instead of fullscreen was adding the following to the `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`:

```
@chromium-browser --new-window --incognito --kiosk http:// --window-position=0,0 --user-data-dir=Default --kiosk`

@chromium-browser --new-window --incognito --kiosk http:// --window-position=4000,0 --user-data-dir='Profile 1' --kiosk`
```

I firstly had some struggles with finding out the window positions but the following worked for me:

I have a 4k Monitor and next to it a normal sized one, so what I did was go to screen settings and go to resolution to find out the size of my HDMI-1 Screen which was the 4k one. It was 3980 x something, so I just did `--window-position=4000,0` on the second one.

I don't know if this is gonna help anyone, but I had to invest quite some time to get this running so I would have appreciated that info. Hope I was able to help someone.

Answer (score -1):

(I wonder if this is still relevant to anyone anymore)

For me two Chromium windows worked (almost) right away without any actual tricks. I opened a Chromium-window, moved it to the secondary screen, maximized it by double-clicking the top-bar and then opened another Chromium window in the primary screen by simply clicking the web-browser icon anew. Voila, two windows.

In order to copy/paste between the two sessions, Chromium (or Google) required of me that I installed a plug-in for off-line usage in my browser.

Happy New Year

Thomas